# Filter based on ranking

Tags: mysql

I have 2 Table Sign up and Like.I want filter based on top like. If user has more like then other it should be on top.

Two Table 
1 First Signup :

```
`signup`(`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `mobile`, `password`,   
`confirm_password`, `email`, `username`, `country_id`, `state_id`, 
`city_id`, `gender`, `occupation_id`, `personal_address`, 
`personal_description`, `personal_status`, `business_name`, 
`business_categories_id`, `business_phone`, `business_email`, 
`business_address`, `business_website`, `services`, `business_status`, 
`personal_profile_photo`, `business_profile_photo`, `created_on`, `otp`, 
`status`)
```

2 Like Table : `b_like`(`id`, `userid`, `profile_id`, `type`, `timestamp`)

i want filter based on top likes

Comment: If user id = 10  like  user id 40  then entry in b_like table  (1 , 10 , 40 , 1 , 2018) second row (2 , 10 , 50 , 1 , 2018 )

Comment: you question  is not clear  .. updated  you question (not comment)  add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: `business_categories_id` - wassat?

Comment: its business category id

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that '*id*' and '*profile_id*' have the same value, you should do something like this:

```
SELECT table_signup.id, COUNT(table_b_like.profile_id) count
FROM signup table_signup
LEFT JOIN b_like table_b_like ON table_signup.id = table_b_like.profile_id
GROUP BY table_signup.id 
order by count desc
```

You get the id (and count) of users from *signup* table that have the most likes in *b_like* table

Comment: Yes user id and id is same and profile_id is also id in like table

Comment: what you get..?